# angularjs directive needs to run if element width, or parent width changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have written a directive which sets style attributes to a div if the parent div resizes, but I also need the same to happen if the actual div resizes. I am unsure how to do this. The directive code is as follows:

```
app.directive('frontTextStyle', function ($compile) {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {



        scope.getWidth = function () {
        return element.parent()[0].offsetWidth;
        };

        scope.$watch(scope.getWidth, function (width) {
            var fs; var v; var h;
            fs = scope.field.fontSize / scope.field.relativeDivWidth * (element.parent()[0].offsetWidth + 1);
            var t = "position: absolute; display: inline-block; overflow:hidden; color: " + scope.field.colour + "; font-family: " + scope.field.font + "; font-size: " + fs + "px;";
            console.log("t1desktop", t);
            attrs.$set("style", t);


            if (scope.field.hAlign == "left") {
                h = " left: 0;";

            }

            if (scope.field.hAlign == "right") {
                h = " right: 0;";
            }

            if (scope.field.hAlign == "center") {
                h = " left:" + ((element.parent()[0].offsetWidth - element[0].offsetWidth) / 2) + "px;";
                console.log("middletest", element.parent()[0].offsetWidth, element[0].offsetWidth)
            }

            if (scope.field.vALign == "top") {
                v = " top: 0;";
            }

            if (scope.field.vAlign == "bottom") {
                v = " bottom: 0;";
            }

            if (scope.field.vAlign == "middle") {

                v = " top: " + ((element.parent()[0].offsetHeight - (fs * 1.42857143)) / 2) + "px;";
            }



            console.log("v", v);
            t += v + h;
            attrs.$set("style", t);




        });
    },
    scope: {
        info: "=",
        field: "="
    }
}
```

});

So the directive runs if the element.parent() resizes - I also need it to run if the element resizes - but if I put two directives on the element, then I get an error saying that there are multiple isolate scopes, and I am not sure if I can alter the watch statement to look for either change.

The attrs.$set is applied twice - first to set the size of the div, as this is set by the text, and the font-size which are data driven. Once this div has been set to the correct size, the top and left are set for the div, so it is positioned appropriately inside the parent.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: So, what is the problem actually? Is it the `an error saying that there are multiple isolate scopes`?

Comment: Hi - sorry for the delay. The problem is that the div does not position itself correctly, because when the directive runs for the first time, it runs before the div (not the parent div) has changed to it's correct size (based on setting the font size first in the directive), so the positioning is too far to the right.